# Which method do I better use, when I need error reporting display control?

Tags: php, error-handling, custom-errors

I want to manage error message display control,

and I Googled for a while,

and I found that there are several ways
to do it.

which method do I have to choose?

The thing I want to do is that

I don't want to PHP
shows up any
errors on users display,

on Production Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [error_reporting()](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_error_reporting.asp)

On production, disable errors by doing:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Report runtime errors on development like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

And report all errors like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

See the above link for a complete list of report_level constants with detailed descriptions, as well as the manual page:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Are there any diffrencies between 
"runtime errors" and "all erros" ?

Comment: This solution seems simple so best for me.

Comment: @Jonathanitou this is the most catastrophic solution actually.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to log all errors to a file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', '/tmp/php_errors.log');
```

On unix, you can watch errors using this command:

```
bash$ tail -f /tmp/php_errors.log
```

Or you can just open the log file in a text editor.

This setup can be used on a production server as well, you can download the php_errors.log file periodically to see if there are any bugs.

Comment: Does this solution logs all errors but do not display to user's moniter?

Comment: "display_errors" function just control wether display errors to moniter?

and error_reporting function controls whether logs error?

Comment: I am confused the diffrencies between them for years.

Comment: Yes, the php_errors.log file should be outside the public_html folder, or at the very least, somewhere that it can't be downloaded directly.

All errors will go into the log file, but users will not see any of them. error_reporting() controls which kinds of errors will be displayed.